# UIScrollView disable scrolling when removeFromSuperView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a .xib file who have one view, one tab bar and other 3 scrollViews, when the user select a new tab bar item I execute this code:

```
//Views e Scrolls
    IBOutlet UIView *myView;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScroll;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScroll2;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScroll3;

@property (nonatomic) UIScrollView *scroll;

-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar
didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{

    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [myView subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

    if(item.tag == 1){
        self.title = @"scroll 1";
        scroll = myScroll;
    }
    if(item.tag == 2){
        self.title = @"scroll 2";
        scroll = myScroll2;
    }
    if(item.tag == 3){
        self.title = @"scroll 3";
        scroll = myScroll3;
    }

    scroll.contentSize = scroll.frame.size;
    scroll.frame = myView.frame;

    scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;

    [myView addSubview:scroll];

    [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

}
```

This code works great, but when I select one of the scrolls that had previously been removed from view, they lose their scrolling (which had not happened before), why this is happening and how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this line here:

```
scroll.contentSize = scroll.frame.size;
```

When your `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` matches its `frame.size`, it doesn't need to scroll (by definition). You need to figure out the actual size of its content and use that. You can at least demonstrate the correct functionality (even if it isn't with correct values) by doing this:

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width*2, scroll.frame.size.height*2);
```

You'll have to find the real content size for yourself, though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your intention correct: Removing a scollview from it superview will also remove it from the responderchain. It cant no longer respond to touch event - thus wont scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The question itself and your purpose of code is not very clear. You may try to explain further. And check this line -

```
scroll.contentSize = scroll.frame.size;
```

A UIScrollView whose contentSize <= frame.size, will not scroll. To make it scroll, contentSize should be bigger than frame.size

You should usually set the contentSize depending on the amount of content (subviews) for the scrollView.

In the next line you changed the frame.size, but I do not think that makes the frame size smaller than contentSize in your case.